# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I added a SDK manually into my swift project that was wrote in obj-c and I create bridging header for the header file of it.
I can use all functions and classes defined in SDK and Xcode knows them (by changing their color and no errors) but when I run the project there is one error and one warning: 
[the issue navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lio4x.png)

warning:

```
ignoring file /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/arashetemad/Documents/MPosDocs/IOS/MESDK.framework/MESDK, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/arashetemad/Documents/MPosDocs/IOS/MESDK.framework/MESDK (3 slices)
```

error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NLBlueToothV100ConnParams", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MPos.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try adding `NLBlueToothV100ConnParams` in `TARGETS -- Build Phases-- Link Binary With Libraries`.

Comment: @JsW nothing happens

Comment: Please search on "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64". This has been discussed many times.

Comment: @matt actually I searched and didn't find anything that could help me then I have to ask a question ...

Comment: Try to test on device. x86_64 is generally the simulator, see if you build for device you get the same errors

Answer (score 0):

If **MESDK** is your framework you need to add the missing architecture in the build settings of MESDK project (`supported architectures`) to support it

If it's not yours, you need to ask from the developer to do it...

Comment: the main error is another one this is not so important